react-input-mask returns underscore at the end of value
I have a nextjs project and I use ant design as a design system, I made a component for input mask, but any mask I put, returns an underscore at the end of the value, even if it is completely filled.

live example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/plxx6x
import { Form, Space, Input, Button } from "antd";
import { useState } from "react";
import MaskedInput from "react-input-mask";
import "./styles.css";

const InputMask = ({ mask, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <MaskedInput mask={mask} {...props}>
      {(inputProps) => <Input {...inputProps} />}
    </MaskedInput>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form onFinish={({ phone }) => setValue(phone)}>
        <Space direction="vertical">
          <Form.Item name="phone" style={{ margin: 0 }}>
            <InputMask mask="(99) 99999-9999" />
          </Form.Item>
          {value && <div>Value: {value}</div>}
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
            Enviar
          </Button>
        </Space>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}

I tried several ways to make this work correctly, apparently it is simple but there is something interfering

I check the code, it's good, just a little tweak and it will be good
the issue is here
const InputMask = ({ mask, ...props }) => {
   return (
        <MaskedInput mask={mask} {...props}>
          {(inputProps) => <Input {...inputProps} />}
        </MaskedInput>
      );
    };

It keeps the placeholder character (_) even when the input is fully filled.
use this line of code it will remove the _ from the end.
<Form onFinish={({ phone }) => setValue(phone.replace(/_/g, ""))}>


Yes, I thought about doing that, but I didn't think it was very correct, especially because I'm going to have several Forms in this project, if I have to do this in all of them it won't look good. I have to solve the problem at the root.
